# Angular - How to call a modal in a component from another component?

Tags: angular, mdbootstrap

I am trying to call a modal (created with Mdbootstrap) in a component from another component,but i struggle how to do it in Angular.
Well this is the code of the modal : [editComponent.html] :

```
<div mdbModal #basicModal="mdbModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myBasicModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()">
          <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title w-100" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="secondary" class="waves-light" aria-label="Close" (click)="basicModal.hide()" mdbWavesEffect>Close</button>
        <button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" mdbWavesEffect>Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And there is another component called [ProduitComponent.html ] where there is a button (Edit),once i click on the button the Modal should appear on the same page.

Thank you !

Comment: Best way is by using triggering it with Subject/Observable(RxJS)

Comment: Did you check official MDB modal documentation? There is a guide for dynamic modals created with `ModalService`: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/angular/modals/basic/#dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can only accomplish this in a handful of ways. If you are trying to execute code within a component from another component, you have to get a reference to said component. Then, you can access public properties/methods with `ComponentRef<Component>.instance`.

I would recommend moving your dialog (modal) to a `DialogService` of some sort so that you can easily invoke the dialog form any component you wish. Since `mdbootstrap` doesn't come with a pre-packaged out of the box dialog, you will probably have to create a `BootStrapModalComponent` and in your service, insert the dialog dynamically using the `ComponentFactory`

Example:

```
const componentFactory = ComponentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyBootstrapModalComponent);
ViewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
```

Then, in your service, you would have logic to run the Component Creation process when they call `dialogOpen` or something. When they call `dialogClose`, then you run similar logic that destroys the dialog.

IMO, the way the Angular Material team did the `MatDialog`/`MatDialog`` is much cleaner. They provide a CDK that you might be able to use to make your bootstrap modals more generic.

Another option is to take a poor-mans route and create a `DialogService` that just has an `EventEmitter`. That `EventEmitter` can be a singleton service that is shared across components to transmit your open/close events between any component. Although this would work without issue, it's not as elegant.